# How to add a dynamically generated route in Play 2.5 Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to use Play to create a simple server in Scala.

I want to provide an endpoint for a webhook that is generated from a secret token set in an environment variable.

`export SECRET_TOKEN="asntoehu"`

I want to create a route like `POST /asntoehu controllers.Application.webhook`

I can't work out how to either pass such an environment variable to conf/routes file or how to manually override routing in my app.

I am using the scala play seed created by running `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8`

Scala 2.5 using Dependency Injection method (so can't use GlobalSettings override)

How should I do this?

Comment: What if you used a route like `/secret/:dynamic` and then evaluate the dynamic part in the code? Ie. have an action that takes `dynamic` as a parameter and then check whether it matches your configured secret thing. Also note that you can use environment variable in the play config.